# Nonexistence for small data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

For context of this question, please refer to page 689 of PDE Evans, 2nd edition. My question is at the bottom.

> As an example, consider this initial-value problem in three space dimensions: $$\begin{cases}u_{tt}-\Delta u - |u|^p = 0 & \text{in }\mathbb{R}^3 \times (0,\infty) \\ \qquad \, \, \, \, \,u=g,u_t = h & \text{on }\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{t=0\}. \end{cases}\tag{8}$$
> Take any smooth initial data with $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} g \, dx > 0, \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} h \, dx > 0 \tag{9}$$ and $\operatorname{spt}g,\operatorname{spt}h \subset B(0,R)$. We will deduce from these conditions alone that there is no solution, provided the exponent $p > 1$ is small enough.

In case $\text{spt}g$ is unfamiliar to some, it means "support", which is also written conventionally as $\operatorname{supp}g$, for example.

> **THEOREM 2** (Nonexistence for small data)**.** Assume that $$1 < p < 1+\sqrt{2}.$$ Then under the above conditions on $g$ and $h$, the initial-value problem $(8)$ does not have a smooth solution $u$ existing for all times $t \ge 0$.

Here is a fragment of the textbook's proof:

> **Proof.** 1. We assume to the contrary that $u$ is in fact a solution and derive a contradiction. Since the initial data have support within $B(0,R)$, Theorem 3 from §12.1.2 implies that $u(\cdot,t)$ is supported within the ball $B(0,R+t)$.
>
> $\quad$ Put $$I(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u \, dx.$$ Then $$I'' = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u_{tt} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |u|^p \, dx.$$

This proof continues, but my question concerns the expression $I''$. I understand the first equality, but how did we obtain the second equality? Namely, why is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u_{tt} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |u|^p \, dx$$ when the PDE in $(8)$ gives $u_{tt}=|u|^p+\Delta u$? Because integrating this gives $$I'' = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u_{tt} \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |u|^p + \Delta u \, dx.$$ For some reason, however, the textbook "omits" the $\Delta u$ term...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just an application of (one of) Green's formulas.

As $u(\cdot, t)$ has support in $B(0,R+t)$, then $u\equiv 0$ outside $B(0,R+t)$; in particular $\nabla u \equiv 0$ on $\partial B(0,r)$ for large enough $r > R + t$.

So
\begin{equation}
\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta u d x = \int_{\partial B(0,r)}\nabla u \cdot \hat{n}\,d S = 0.
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\Delta u\, dx = \lim_{r \to \infty}\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta u\, d x = \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{\partial B(0,r)}\nabla u \cdot \hat{n}\,d S = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Related quetion on the same proof: On page 691 of the textbook, the author says that, since $I' > 0$, $$I''I' \ge cI' I^{1+\epsilon}(1+t)^{-\mu};$$ and thus $$((I')^2)' \ge c(I^{2+\epsilon})(1+t)^{-\mu})'+c\mu I^{2+\epsilon}(1+t)^{-\mu+1} \ge c(I^{2+7\epsilon}(1+t)^{-\mu})'.$$ If I may ask, how does first the inequality relation for $((I')^2)'$ follow? I am tempted to say that $((I')^2)'=2I'I''$, and then apply the top inequality to the bottom one. And that product rule was used upon differentiation of the other side.

Comment: I believe that is how the inequality is obtained - there may be some "fussing" around with the constants ($c$ may change from one line to the next) which I haven't checked in detail.